# Scaling the y-axis with Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to scale the y-axis with [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)? I don't want to change the y-limit, I just want to extend the physical space.

```
^      ^
|      |
|      |
+----> |
Before +---->
       After
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a larger height value when you instantiate the figure:

```
from pylab import *
x = linspace(0, 10*pi, 2**10)
y = sin(x)
figure(figsize=(5, 10))
plot(x, y)
show()
```

Where `figsize=(width, height)` and defaults to `(8, 6)`.  Values are in inches (the `dpi` keyword arg can be used to define the [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) for the figure, and there's a default value in your `matplotlibrc` file)

For a figure already created, I believe there is a `set_size_inches(width, height)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the subplots_adjust function to control the abount of whitespace:

```
fig.subplots_adust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
```

There is an icon on the toolbar to do this interactively with a widget

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, since it just resizes the plot area, i.e. I can make extra space for the xticks.